# Replace template by plugin

Tags: woocommerce

The instruction to replace the template like `cart.php` is to create a duplicate in the theme directory like

`/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php`.

But my question is, can I make it in a plugin instead of a theme like:

`/wp-content/plugins/yourplugin/woocommerce/cart/cart.php`

Will this work? If yes, is it a good practice or it’s not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. WooCommerce provides a filter just for that:

```
// Allow 3rd party plugin filter template file from their plugin.
$filter_template = apply_filters( 'wc_get_template', $template, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path );
```